# Issue on Point Graphic Order in ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to add a point to map like this:

```
var point = new esri.geometry.Point(19.82, 41.33);
point = esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(point);
var symbol = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Map-Markers-Icons-Demo-PNG/128/Map-Marker-Marker-Outside-Chartreuse.png", 32, 32);
var graphic = new esri.Graphic(point, symbol);
var layer = new esri.layers.GraphicsLayer();
layer.add(graphic);
map.addLayer(layer);
map.reorderLayer(layer,1);
```

however the marker is showing on the back of borders layers! I tried to keep the point at first level using:

```
map.reorderLayer(layer,1);
```

but it didn't work! Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What version of the API are you using?

Comment: What is the type of the layer (you called it the "borders layer") that the GraphicsLayer is showing up behind?